# Is $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ dense in $L^p(A)$ when $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is measurable and $1\leq p \leq \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Define $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to be all continuous functions with compact support. I managed to show the claim in the case $1\leq p <\infty$ and $A=\mathbb{R}^n$. This was done in steps:

1. Use Urysohn's lemma to show that you can approximate characteristic functions of measurable sets by functions in $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
2. From 1) it follows that simple functions can be approximated by
   functions in $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
3. Show that simple functions are dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. From
   this it immediately follows along with 2) that
   $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense.

I also think that when $p=\infty$ the claim does not hold. This is because the uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous. Therefore one cannot approximate for example the step function $\chi_{[0, \infty)}$ by functions in $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

So my question is: can we use the same proof for arbitrary measurable set $A$? Can we just conclude that $C_0(A)\subset L^p(A)$ is dense and extend the functions in $C_0(A)$ by zero to $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$? Or am I missing something crucial here?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, added it now.

Comment: Well, continuous functions on an arbitrary set are not really useful. To use continuity (and differentiability, etc...), you need that the functions are defined on an **open** set. This said, the crucial point of the proof you sketched is Urysohn's lemma. You should try and see if it works on an arbitrary set. I bet it does not.

Comment: The version of Urysohn's lemma I used is the following: Let $X$ be proper metric space, $K\subset U$ where $K$ is compact and $U$ open. Then there is $f\in C_0(X)$ s.t. $0\leq f\leq 1$, $f|K=1$ and $\text{spt}(f)\subset U$. I can't see why this would fail for a general subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Or wait a minute, I guess the problem comes from the fact that even if $X$ is proper then it does not necessarily hold that a general $A\subset X$ is proper. Am I right in this?

Comment: What is "proper"? Closed balls are compact? Then, yes, a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ needs not be proper (for example, $\mathbb Q$ is not).

Comment: Yes, that is my definition of proper. And yes, that was the counterexample I also had in mind.

Comment: On the other hand, the answer to your question was easy, so my comment is misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f\in L^{p}(A)$ then extend $f$ to $L^{p}(\mathbb R^{n})$ by making it $0$ outside $A$. Approximate $g$ by $C_0(\mathbb R^{n})$ function $h$. Then $h$ approximates $f$ on $A$. I don't think the question has anything to do with $C_0(A)$ (which does not even make sense for a general measurable set $A$).

Comment: Oh, it was that easy. Thank you very much.